# What is the point of Riverpod Provider ref.watch

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-riverpod

Unless you’re using something like StateNoticationProvider, listening to or watching a normal Provider doesn’t seem to update
the UI even though the object the provider is returning changes. So when is a normal provider’s listen or watch used? By normal provider I mean the Provider class in contrast to StateNotifierProvider or sth like that. It looks like a basic counter example using riverpod requires too much boilerplate… StateNotfier, StateNotifierProvider, then you have to think about making those objects immutable while also updating their values… etc etc. Is there a way to watch Poviders and not have to worry about rebuilding UI (just do
it automatically when the object being listened to changes)

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling around, it looks to me like the base `Provider` is useful when you want to combine multiple providers and compute another provider. In that case, Provider's `watch` works as expected!